# jQuery ContextMenu doesnot appear fully if element is at the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

Okay I guess the subject line explains most of it, put still I'll elaborate a little more. Okay here is the scenario,

I have a tree of elements (element names are obtained from a database so can be from none to 1000s), every element that is created comes with contextMenu functionality (i.e., you can right click on them to view a contextMenu with 4-5 actions). Now it seems to work fine if I scroll up and down the page, but some pages do not have scrollbars (as per the requirement of the project), hence if I click on the bottom most element to view list of actions in a contextMenu, all I see is half of the contextMenu and the remaining half goes out of the bounds of the browser window (Please see the image below),

[image]

My question is, is there a way to move the position of the contextMenu so that it always remains within bounds of the browser window. 
Looking forward to your replies and Help,

Kind Regards,

rac3B3nn0n

Comment: did you create the tree and context menu by your self or can you give some links to sources?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using jquery UI, but it has a position utility with a collision offset that will keep an item inside the viewport:  http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/ -- it may/may not work for you, but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Thanks Manuel and swatkins ... :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem for a very large context menu (>50 elements).
I solved it as follows:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .limit-context-size { max-height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll; }
</style>
...
$.contextMenu({
...
  className: "limit-context-size",
...
});
```

This causes the menu to scroll vertically. The 300px was picked based on the context menu font size.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou all, Well I've figured it out. Actually it was my own fault, in order to fix position bug for IE6, I had changed a little code inside jquery.contextMenu.js, reimplemented that in a different way just worked for me.

Thank you all for all your help and effort

Regards,
rac3B3nn0n

Comment: can you share the code that you changed to fix the position? thanks